# Azure Front Door - Managed SSL certificate - Domain Validation Stuck

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-front-door

I have been trying to provision a managed SSL cert but it **does not go past domain validation** (it seems to get stuck)

[image: vildation stuck]

What I tried:

1. Create Correct CNAME (using Azure DNS Zone)
2. Validated the ADVERIFY subdomain exists also

I have not received any email that the docs mention could happen if automatic validation via CNAME doesn't happen

I waited 3 days and still nothing and I tried to delete and recreate it a few times and each time it is stuck

Questions:

1. Has anybody with this issue managed to find the solution?
2. Is there a way to check/debug/audit further details on what might be wrong? (I don't see anything in the azure activity log either)

Comment: Have you tried to query your DNS server directly to see if the value of the CNAME record is correct?

Comment: usually works within 10-20min. I run this quite often and never had to wait that long. Maybe either recreate or if it still does not work, open a support request